# How can I force Whatsapp for desktop to use a proxy in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, whatsapp

I use Whatsapp for Desktop on my work-provided Windows 10 PC.  Because it's work-provided, I alternate between being on the corporate VPN and connecting directly to the internet.

With the latest release of Whatsapp for Desktop, Whatsapp can no longer connect when I'm on the VPN.  It would appear that it's trying to bypass the proxy.  Is there any way to force the application to use the proxy?

---

Edit: This question was originally asked on Windows 10, but the problem persists on Windows 11, using the version of Whatsapp on the Microsoft Store.

Comment: I can see the same problem, new whatsapp and Fiddler proxy with whatsapp pictures and other files. when Fiddler is closed (or not used as the default system proxy) the whatsapp pictures (and recordings) is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the answer above, you can also install web.whatsapp.com as a standalone app, using Chrome or Edge feature to install a website like an app.

Chrome:
https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en

Edge:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/install-manage-or-uninstall-apps-in-microsoft-edge-0c156575-a94a-45e4-a54f-3a84846f6113

Doing this no more proxy problem

Comment: This is an excellent workaround!

Answer (score 9):

Our IT department raised this with WhatsApp and this was the feedback:

> IT has not blocked Whatsapp desktop. The vendor made a
>   change which caused a problem and they refused to accept it as a fault
>   report.
>
> I reported to Whatsapp support that their latest version of 8th Nov.
>   does not read the proxy.pac script.  Their response was “WhatsApp is
>   not designed to be used with proxy configurations”

I've been using https://web.whatsapp.com/ in a browser window, which works fine as the browser uses the proxy.